# NodeJs facing the issue while using async waterfall

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async.js

I am calling 2 API request 1 after another so I decided to use the waterfall model but I am facing the issue in it

I have tried so much but not able to solve the issue.

Below is my code:

```
var unirest = require("unirest");
var async = require("async")

exports.user = (req, res, next) => {
    const qry = req.params.id
    async.waterfall([
        (nextCall) => {
            var req = unirest("GET", API_URL1);
            req.query({
               // some query
            });
            req.headers({
               // some headers 
            });
            req.end(function(subCount) {
                // if (resp.error) throw new Error(resp.error);
                var channelSubCount = subCount.body
                nextCall(null, data)
            });
        },
        (data, nextCall => {
            console.log(channelSubCount, 'data')
            var reqs = unirest("GET", API_URL2);

            reqs.query({
              // some query
            });

            reqs.headers({
                // some headers
            });

            reqs.end(function(res) {
                // if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
                console.log(res.body);
                return nextCall(null, {
                    name: 'abc',
                    photo: 'src',
                    count: data
                })
            });
        })
    ], function(finalData) {
        // if (error) { alert('Something is wrong!'); }
        console.log('final')
        res.status(200).json(
            finalData
        );
    });
};
```

ERROR:
Reference Error: data is not defined

I don't understand why this is happening.

Also some please show me the right way to implement the above things with optimizations.

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to close parentheses here in your second arrow function definition:

```
(data, nextCall => {
```

It's still a valid JavaScript, but the interpreter now treats `data` not as a function incoming parameter (as you need), but as a variable. But it's not defined anywhere, therefore you have that error.

Make it like this and it will work:

```
(data, nextCall) => {
```